# Mysql Database Name Restrictions

Tags: mysql, database

I am building a system where while the admin is installing it, one of the steps is to create a database (from the system). So my question is, how should I validate the database name? I found it can't be longer than 64 chars but is this the only restriction? I tested some db names with special characters in phpmyadmin which didn't give an error.

Comment: Check out [8.2. Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html) in the docs

Answer (score 28):

MySQL database naming restrictions:

- Cannot be longer than 64 characters.
- Cannot contain `/` `\` or `.` characters.
- Cannot contain characters that are not permitted in file names.
- Cannot end with space characters.

[More information here](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30875).

Answer (score 15):

The Regex for this:

```
^[^\\/?%*:|\"<>.]{1,64}$
```